# Is there a way to add some basic scripting to MkDocs when writing in MarkDown?

Tags: css, templates, jinja2, markdown, mkdocs

I have a documentation site using MkDocs. It contains a list of documents, all with the same basic structure (we only have a list of experimental notebooks). Each notebook (written in a separate MarkDown file) should contain an author + date in the beginning using the following:

```
<style>table, td, th {border:none!important; font-size:15px}</style>

|                |                             |
| -------------- | :-------------------------- |
| **Author(s):** | First Author, Second Author |
| **Date:**      | 2024-01-23                  |
```

What I would like to have is some kind of templating that enables the users to avoid adding the above lines (eg. avoid adding CSS) but instead just specifying the list of authors and a date. This would enable me as a documentation owner to change the formatting later if needed without changing each `.md` file content.

I read about Jinja templates and wonder if it could be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `metadata` also called `frontend` data, as described in the [yaml-style-meta-data section](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/writing-your-docs/#yaml-style-meta-data). Such information is placed at the beginning of your markdown file. The content can then be used to generate content.

The `macro` plugin is made for this and can be found here https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io

Comment: I am the author of mkdocs-macros. Yes, you could perfectly do that, by creating a `main.py` module, where you define the function that will generate the string. You will find [directions and an example of how to do that](https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/macros/).

Answer (score 3):

My notes after studying a problem that is similar to yours:

### One example using global blocks

**in your case** you should look at mkdocs with jinja macros.
The metadata can be directly accessed in your markdown.

So you can place at start of the document

```yaml
authors: First A, Second A
docdate: 2024-01-23
```

and then in the document text uses `{{ authors }}`, it will be replaced.

You requested to use this globally without changing the markdown files. This can be done by including a block of markdown from an external file in your document.   First setup [mkdocs include plugin](https://github.com/mondeja/mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin) and then use something like this:

```markdown
---
authors: First, second
docdate: 2024-01-23
---
{% include-markdown "../authortable.md" %}
```

In the authortable you can directly put your layout for the author table, and include the metadata. The include is done before variable expantion.

Your include file could be:

```markdown
<style>table, td, th {border:none!important; font-size:15px}</style>

|                |                             |
| -------------- | :-------------------------- |
| **Author(s):** | {{authors}}                 |
| **Date:**      | {{docdate}}                 |
```

### Other approaches

There are other ways of course.

You can make a python macro and call this with the metadata variables:

```
  {{ make_the_table (authors , docdate) }}
```

The advantage of the macro approach is that you have the full power of Python, and can use databases, condition, file system properties, etc etc.

You can also automatically modify the raw markdown without having any tags in the documents, using a method `on_post_page_macros(env)` as described in [advanced macro](https://mkdocs-macros-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/).